# How can I determine which C++ compiler is used if I only can alter the C++ code and inspect console output?

Tags: c++

Suppose there's a system like [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) - a black box that can accept C++ code, compile it, run it and present the console output. How could I determine what C++ compiler such system uses?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could have an `ifdef` fest to detect what the compiler is, using all the information compiled [in this page](http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html).

Comment: In this case you can recognise the error messages as GCC-style, and [it turns out it's 4.1.2](http://codepad.org/CSDZTB5t)

Comment: It is good that this page be periodically pointed to, so that we can bookmark it again. Thanks.